# VB.NET Display progress of file decryption?

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I'm using this code to encrypt/decrypt files:

```
Public Shared Sub encryptordecryptfile(ByVal strinputfile As String, _
                                         ByVal stroutputfile As String, _
                                         ByVal bytkey() As Byte, _
                                         ByVal bytiv() As Byte, _
                                         ByVal direction As CryptoAction)
            Try
                fsInput = New System.IO.FileStream(strinputfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                fsOutput = New System.IO.FileStream(stroutputfile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
                fsOutput.SetLength(0)
                Dim bytbuffer(4096) As Byte
                Dim lngbytesprocessed As Long = 0
                Dim lngfilelength As Long = fsInput.Length
                Dim intbytesincurrentblock As Integer
                Dim cscryptostream As CryptoStream
                Dim csprijndael As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
                Select Case direction
                    Case CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt
                        cscryptostream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, _
                        csprijndael.CreateEncryptor(bytkey, bytiv), _
                        CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                    Case CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
                        cscryptostream = New CryptoStream(fsOutput, _
                        csprijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytkey, bytiv), _
                        CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                End Select
                While lngbytesprocessed < lngfilelength
                    intbytesincurrentblock = fsInput.Read(bytbuffer, 0, 4096)
                    cscryptostream.Write(bytbuffer, 0, intbytesincurrentblock)
                    lngbytesprocessed = lngbytesprocessed + CLng(intbytesincurrentblock)
                End While
                cscryptostream.Close()
                fsInput.Close()
                fsOutput.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
```

Is I need to get the percentage of this process being done as an integer. I am going to use a background worker, so I need to call for this sub from the background worker and be able to keep refreshing a progress bar that the background worker reports to. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ya, I saw that, but I need to get the percentage of the encryption/decryption being done first. How do I do that?

Comment: `Dim percent As Integer = CInt((CDbl(lngbytesprocessed)  / CDbl(lngfilelength)) * 100)` .. are you asking for that, or are you asking how to pass this value to the progress bar from the background thread?

Comment: percentage can be calculated as `Dim percentage as Integer = Math.Floor((lngbytesprocessed/lngfilelength)*100)` inside the while loop. And the [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) works on the same thread as UI if the background worker is initiated form UI thread.

Comment: Thanks very much, Bansi! I used  BackgkroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentage) and in the BackgroundWorker.ProgressChangedEvent I put ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage and it's working great. However, I was wondering, is it also possible to get the percentage of this being done? ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(encryptPath, encryptPath & ".zip")

Comment: I rolled back your edit (sorry).  SO is not a forum and doesnt have "threads".  It works best as one question:one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to make your cryptor more efficient and other issues:

- A method like `encryptordecryptfile` which then requires a "mode" argument to know which action to take means it really might be better off as 2 methods
- The way you are going, you will be raising a blizzard of `ProgressChanged` events which the `ProgressBar` wont be able to keep up with given the animation.  A 700K file will result in 170 or so progress reports of tiny amounts
- Some of the crypto steps can be incorporated
- You have a lot of things not being disposed of; you could run out of resources if you run a number of files thru it in a loop.

It might be worth noting that you can replace the entire `While` block with `fsInput.CopyTo(cscryptostream)` to process the file all at once.  This doesnt allow progress reporting though.  Its also not any faster.

Rather than a `BackgroundWorker` (which will work fine), you might want to implement it as a `Task`.  The reason for this is that all those variables need to make their way from something like a button click to the `DoWork` event where your method is actually called.  Rather than using global variables or a class to hold them, a Task works a bit more directly (but does involve one extra step when reporting progress).  First, a revised `EncryptFile` method:

```
Private Sub EncryptFile(inFile As String,
                        outFile As String,
                        pass As String,
                        Optional reporter As ProgressReportDelegate = Nothing)

    Const BLOCKSIZE = 4096
    Dim percentDone As Integer = 0
    Dim totalBytes As Int64 = 0
    Dim buffSize As Int32

    ' Note A
    Dim key = GetHashedBytes(pass)
    Dim iv = GetRandomBytes(16)

    Dim cryptor As ICryptoTransform

    ' Note B
    Using fsIn As New FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
        fsOut As New FileStream(outFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        fsOut.SetLength(0)

        ' Note C
        'ToDo: work out optimal block size for Lg vs Sm files
        If fsIn.Length > (2 * BLOCKSIZE) Then
            ' use buffer size to limit to 20 progress reports
            buffSize = CInt(fsIn.Length \ 20)
            ' to multiple of 4096
            buffSize = CInt(((buffSize + BLOCKSIZE - 1) / BLOCKSIZE) * BLOCKSIZE)
            ' optional, limit to some max size like 256k?
            'buffSize = Math.Min(buffSize, BLOCK256K)
        Else
            buffSize = BLOCKSIZE
        End If

        Dim buffer(buffSize-1) As Byte

        ' Note D
        ' write the IV to "naked" fs
        fsOut.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length)

        Using rij = Rijndael.Create()
            rij.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126
            Try
                cryptor = rij.CreateEncryptor(key, iv)
                Using cs As New CryptoStream(fsOut, cryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

                    Dim bytesRead As Int32

                    Do Until fsIn.Position = fsIn.Length

                        bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffSize)
                        cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)

                        If reporter IsNot Nothing Then
                            totalBytes += bytesRead
                            percentDone = CInt(Math.Floor((totalBytes / fsIn.Length) * 100))
                            reporter(percentDone)
                        End If
                    Loop
                End Using
            Catch crEx As CryptographicException
                ' ToDo: Set breakpoint and inspect message
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' ToDo: Set breakpoint and inspect message
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

**Note A**
One of the standard crypto tasks it could handle is creating the Key and IV arrays for you.  These are pretty simple and could be shared/static members.

```
Public Shared Function GetHashedBytes(data As String) As Byte()
    Dim hBytes As Byte()

    ' or SHA512Managed
    Using hash As HashAlgorithm = New SHA256Managed()
        ' convert data to bytes:
        Dim dBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)
        ' hash the result:
        hBytes = hash.ComputeHash(dBytes)

    End Using

    Return hBytes
End Function

Public Shared Function GetRandomBytes(size As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim data(size - 1) As Byte

    Using rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
        ' fill the array 
        rng.GetBytes(data)
    End Using
    Return data

End Function
```

As will be seen later, you can store the IV in the encrypted file rather than saving and managing it in code.

**Note B**
`Using` blocks close and dispose of resources for you.  Basically, if something has a `Dispose` method, then you should wrap it in a `Using` block.

**Note C**
You dont want to report progress for every block read, that will just overwhelm the ProgressBar. Rather than another variable to keep track of when the progress has changed by some amount, this code starts by creating a buffer size which is 5% of the input file size so there will be about 20 reports (every 5%).

As the comments indicate, you may want to add some code to set minimum/maximum buffer size.  Doing so would change the progress report frequency.

**Note D**
You can write the IV() to the filestream before you wrap it in the CryptoStream (and of course read it back first when Decrypting).  This prevents you from having to store the IV.

The last part is kicking this off as a Task:

```
Dim t As Task
t = Task.Run(Sub() EncryptFile(inFile, oFile, "MyWeakPassword", 
                   AddressOf ReportProgress))
...
```

What a BGW does is execute the work on one thread, but progress is reported on the UI thread.  As a `Task`, all we need to do is use `Invoke`:

```
Delegate Sub ProgressReportDelegate(value As Int32)

Private Sub ReportProgress(v As Int32)
    If progBar.InvokeRequired Then
        progBar.Invoke(Sub() progBar.Value = v)
    Else
        progBar.Value = v
        progBar.Invalidate()
    End If
End Sub
```

The Encryptor will work either directly or as a Task.  For small files, you can omit the progress report entirely:

```
' small file, no progress report:
EncryptFile(ifile, oFile, "MyWeakPassword")

' report progress, but run on UI thread
EncryptFile(ifile, oFile, "MyWeakPassword", 
            AddressOf ReportProgress)

' run as task
Dim t As Task
t = Task.Run(Sub() EncryptFile(ifile, oFile, "MyWeakPassword", 
                AddressOf ReportProgress))
```

...and if you had a list of files to do, you could run them all at once and perhaps report total progress.